# (SOLVED) Simplify $\cos^{-1}\left( \frac{7}{2}\left( 1+\cos{2x} \right) + \sqrt{\left( \sin^{2}{x} - 48\cos^{2}{x} \right)}\sin{x}\right)$

Tags: trigonometry, inverse-function

I need a little help in simplification of an ITF problem of a college entrance exam I got stuck in.

$$\cos^{-1}\left( \frac{7}{2}\left( 1+\cos{2x} \right) + \sqrt{\left( \sin^{2}{x} - 48\cos^{2}{x} \right)}\sin{x}\right)$$

with 
$ x\in \left( 0,\frac{\pi}{2} \right) $

---

What I'm doing:

$y=\cos ^{-1}\left(\frac{7}{2}(1+\cos 2 x)+\sqrt{\left(\sin ^2 x-48 \cos ^2 x\right)} \sin x\right)$

$\quad=\cos ^{-1}\left((7 \cos x)(\cos x)+\sqrt{1-49 \cos ^2 x} \sqrt{1-\cos ^2 x}\right)$
......stuck

Thanks!

Comment: Please consider commenting if there is something to improve instead of downvoting recklessly. Not everyone is 40 years old with 20 years of experience with maths. Some of us are in high school and get stuck sometimes.

Comment: Try to evaluate the expression at values where the cosine and sine are known, like at $\frac{\pi}{3}, \frac{\pi}{4},\frac{\pi}{6}$ and so on. See if you can guess a pattern out of that. Also, evaluating the general expression in Wolfram Alpha gives no result, so can you check and let me know if the expression as written is correct?

Comment: In fact, it cannot be right, unless you want to wade into complex numbers. The square root, for small values of $x$, will not have a positive argument because $\sin x (\sin^2 x - 48 \cos^2 x) < 0$ for small positive values of $x$.

Comment: @StinkingBishop Thanks for explaining that. I'm new on here. I'll edit the question :)

Comment: It should be $\sqrt{\left( \sin^{2}{x} - 48\cos^{2}{x} \right)}\,\sin{x}$ not $\sqrt{\left( \sin^{2}{x} - 48\cos^{2}{x} \right)\sin{x}}$.

Comment: Certainly not much point answering the question if we are not sure what the formula should look like. One misplaced symbol here may turn an easy problem into an unsolvable one!

Comment: @David Oh God, I didn't notice that. You're right. This was a question from a reputed college's entrance exam. Seems they made a mistake in formatting

Comment: @44yu5h are you familiar with the formula: $\arccos x-\arccos y$?

Comment: @Adithya I wasn't. I am in class 10th we haven't been taught ITF yet.  Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $\cos^{-1}\frac17\le x\le\frac\pi2$, and take $\theta$ in $[0,\frac\pi2]$ such that $\cos\theta=7\cos x$.  Then
$$\eqalign{
  \frac{7}{2}(1+\cos 2 x)+{}&\sqrt{\left(\sin ^2 x-48 \cos ^2 x\right)} \sin x\cr
  &=(7 \cos x)(\cos x)+\sqrt{1-49 \cos ^2 x}\sin x\cr
  &=\cos x\cos\theta+\sin x\sin\theta\cr
  &=\cos(x-\theta)\cr}$$
and so
$$\cos^{-1}({\rm this})=x-\theta=x-\cos^{-1}(7\cos x)\ ,$$
provided $0\le x-\cos^{-1}(7\cos x)\le\pi$, and this is true for all $x$ in the range stated above.